# Amazon Data Pipeline: List of acceptable types for Custom Format

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using DataPipeline to pipe a CSV from S3 into RDS
As part of this process, I'm using a `DataFormat` which is a `CSV`
According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-custom.html) , I can have `STRING`, `DATETIME` and `INT`

Are there other types that I can use? (namely date, floating numbers, etc etc)

Thanks!

Comment: DATE, FLOAT work. Would be great to have the complete list

Answer (score 0):

you can use any data type that is supported by the database you are using. Datapipeline does not impose any restriction on datatypes you can use.